Thread-based Network Server
I have set up a simple tcl server which can be accessed in https://elotor-tcl-http-server-demo.hf.space/
proc Server {startTime channel clientaddr clientport} {
    puts "Connection from $clientaddr registered"
    fconfigure $channel -buffering line
    fileevent $channel readable [list Echo $channel $startTime]
}

proc Echo {sock startTime} {
    if { [catch {gets $sock line}] || [eof $sock] } {
        close $sock
        return
    }
  
    set now [clock seconds]
    set htmlContent "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>Test Page</title></head>
    <body><h1>Hello World</h1>
    [expr {$now - $startTime}] seconds since start.</br>$line</body>
    </html>
    "
    puts $sock "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    puts $sock "Content-Type: text/html"
    puts $sock "Content-Length: [string length $htmlContent]"
    puts $sock ""
    puts $sock $htmlContent
    puts $sock "EOF"
    flush $sock
    close $sock
}

socket -server [list Server [clock seconds]] -myaddr 0.0.0.0 7860

proc bgerror msg {
  puts stderr "[clock format [clock seconds]] $msg\n$::errorInfo"
}

vwait forever

I'm considering using threads instead of events, but I don't know if it is worth it, nor how to do it.
I tried the approach from https://www.activestate.com/blog/concurreny-tcl-weaving-threads/
package require Thread

proc NewConnection {startTime channel clientaddr clientport} {
  puts "Connection from $clientaddr registered"
  set t [thread::create {
    proc HandleConnection {channel startTime} {
      fconfigure $channel -buffering none
      set data {}
      while {![eof $channel]} {
        if {[gets $channel line] < 0} {
          continue
        }
        append data $line \n
      }
      set now [clock seconds]
      set htmlContent "
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head><title>Test Page</title></head>
      <body><h1>Hello World</h1>
      [expr {$now - $startTime}] seconds since start.</br>$line</body>
      </html>
      "
      puts $channel {HTTP/1.1 200 OK}
      puts $channel {Content-Type: text/html}
      puts $channel "Content-Length: [string length $htmlContent]"
      puts $channel {}
      puts $channel $htmlContent
      puts $channel EOF
      close $channel
      thread::release
    }
    thread::wait
  }]
  thread::transfer $t $channel
  thread::send -async $t [list HandleConnection $channel $startTime]
}

socket -server _Accept -myaddr 0.0.0.0 7860
proc _Accept {s ipaddr port} {
  after idle [list NewConnection [clock seconds] $s $ipaddr $port]
}

proc bgerror msg {
  puts stderr "[clock format [clock seconds]] $msg\n$::errorInfo"
}

vwait forever

But I get the following error:
Connection from XX.XX.XX.XX registered
Error from thread tid0x7f2693dddb38
error writing "sock7f2693e25e00": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts $channel {HTTP/1.1 200 OK}"
    (procedure "HandleConnection" line 19)
    invoked from within
"HandleConnection sock7f2693e25e00 1714214861"
Connection from XX.XX.XX.XX registered
Error from thread tid0x7f2693d46b38
error writing "sock7f2693e26080": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts $channel {HTTP/1.1 200 OK}"
    (procedure "HandleConnection" line 19)
    invoked from within
"HandleConnection sock7f2693e26080 1714214862"
Connection from XX.XX.XX.XX registered
Error from thread tid0x7f2693c8fb38
error writing "sock7f2693e26380": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts $channel {HTTP/1.1 200 OK}"
    (procedure "HandleConnection" line 19)
    invoked from within
"HandleConnection sock7f2693e26380 1714214863"
Connection from XX.XX.XX.XX registered
Error from thread tid0x7f2693b98b38
error writing "sock7f2693e26e20": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts $channel {HTTP/1.1 200 OK}"
    (procedure "HandleConnection" line 19)
    invoked from within
"HandleConnection sock7f2693e26e20 1714214864"


You probably ought to also log the first line read from the socket in your worker. With HTTP, that will tell you particularly the verb and the resource name, and that might tell you whether those errors are a big problem or a minor bug.
The error is caused by an early close of the socket by the other side (with why being awkward to diagnose without verb and resource). It probably ought to be treated as a non-error case here; the correct resolution of the issue is to just close the socket at this end too.
try {
   puts $chan ...
   puts $chan ...
} trap {POSIX EPIPE} {} {
   # Empty body; we just throw this error away
} finally {
   close $chan
}

